# Laravel app with separate php-fpm and nginx servers

Tags: php, nginx

Is it possible to run a Laravel app on two separated server, one with NGINX, another with PHP-FPM?
I wanted to create an upstream of PHP-FPM servers for load balancing. I've tried some NGINX configurations but it seems that both NGINX and PHP-FPM needs Laravel app files.
Note: I have separate server for static files.

```
[user] -request-> [nginx without laravel files] -> [php-fpm upstream with laravel files]
```

[image]

**UPDATE**

```
upstream php_pool {
    server 192.168.1.1:9000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com;

    index index.php;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/q_access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/q_error.log info;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/index.php /index.php;
    }


    location ~ \.php$ {
        index index.php;
        fastcgi_pass php_pool;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

I don't know what should i set for root directory cause there isn't any Laravel app files in that server. And how config `\.php$` location properly?

Comment: One more question: Is it normal to create multiple php-fpm pool in one server? If yes, can i use this method for php-fpm upstream?

Comment: It is possible. Post exactly what you are trying to do to achieve this.

Comment: @DanilaVershinin I posted my scenario plan, since our app bottleneck in PHP, we want to create multiple instances for load balancing.

Comment: fpm servers usually run a local unix socket. Just change it to TCP and your nginx can connect to it. The configs are `Listen` and `listen.allowed_clients` in fpm.

Comment: @DanielW. That's right and we have setup just like that, my problem is how config nginx so there is no need for laravel app files in nginx server.

Comment: So your question is "how to give nginx access to the static files"? The setup in your question looks good, I don't get what problems you're actually facing with that setup :)

Comment: @DanielW. Since our Laravel app files doesn't exists in NGINX server (they are placed in FPM servers),  how configure NGINX for this plan? Because NGINX can't find index.php so app doesn't work. It seems that Laravel app files should be on the NGINX server too.

Comment: NGINX receives a request to `/` and forwards that to fpm. nginx doesnt need to know about files, it just forwards to fpm. Don't install laravel on nginx, nginx doesn't know how to handle php files.

Comment: @DanielW. That is exactly what i think but it doesn't work for me. I will post my config in details, maybe something with my config

Answer (score 0):

We found solution for our scenario. PHP location should be like this:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass php_pool;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/app/public$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

With this change (SCRIPT_FILENAME) there isn't need for Laravel app files to be on the NGINX server cause all PHP requests will proxied to PHP-FPM servers.